# Array being accessed out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a problem that I am still working on for class. I need to encrypt a message using a basic character change. I have coded everything but I am having issues with a for loop that is suppose to handle character replacements.For some reason it keeps trying to access my array outside of bounds even thought I am using the array length as a limit. I am missing something but I am not sure where. It should work. I have two files. I am basically taking a message, changing it to char array, comparing the letters to find out what they are and then replacing them as needed. Could you point out what I have missed?

Also note: I know I am not suppose to use == but if I use .equals, .compareTo, or anything like that I get a "char cannot be dereferenced" error. They only time it doesn't do that is if I use a ==. If you could also let me why that is a thing or at least point me to where I can understand why that is happening I would be grateful.

```
                                    driver
     /**
Program Name: Driver
Date:4/14/2016

Program Description: This program is going to handle the window where the user enters data. 
It is also going to be what is going to call the methods of the Actions class
Methods: Driver(),destination(), message(),
*/
import javax.swing.*;    // For the Swing classes
import java.awt.event.*; // For the ActionListener Interface

import java.util.Scanner; //for the keyboard


public class Driver extends JFrame
{
 //delcare
  private String locationLetters; //this is going hold the users letter selection
  private String moo; //this is going to hold the users message  
  private boolean error; //this is going to check the location input for errors. 

  private String locH; //for the holder of location selection
  private String messH; //to hold the message before change it to an array 

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//to make the keyboard

  Actions loc = new Actions();
  Actions mess = new Actions();
  /**
  This method is the constuctor that is going to make the window for the program to use. 
  */
 public Driver()
 {
  System.out.println("sup nerd");


  destination();
  message();

  System.out.println(moo + ": The Top level return");
 }//end of Driver()

 public String destination()
 {
  //this to make a loop for getting input and checking it for errors. It get input and passes the input
  //to the actions file for error checking
  do{

   System.out.println("Please enter the two charater key for the location you want to message");
   locationLetters = keyboard.next();

   error = loc.error(locationLetters);
   if(error == true)
    System.out.println("You have entered and incorrect location. Please enter a vaild location");
   else
    break;
  }while(error == true);  


 locH = loc.getCountry(locationLetters); 
 return locH;

 }//end of destination()

 public String message()
 {
  System.out.println("Please enter the message you would like to have encrypted.");
  moo = keyboard.nextLine();

  moo = moo.toUpperCase();


  messH = mess.encrypt(moo);

  System.out.println(moo + ": The original input");

  System.out.println(messH + ": Making sure encrypt works");
 return messH; 
 }//end of message()

 public static void main(String[] arg)
 {

  new Driver();


 }//end of main

}//end of Driver class






                                  actions
import static java.lang.Character.*;

/**
Program Name: Action
Date:4/14/2016

Program Description: This program is going to handle all the encryption actions as well
loction where the message is being sent. 
Methods:Location(), 
*/


public class Actions
{
 //decare 

 public boolean error(String locHA) 
 {
  boolean error = true; //set the boolean value
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("FR"))
   error = false;
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("GB"))
   error = false; 
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("CA"))
   error = false;
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("JA"))
   error = false;
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("RU"))
   error = false;
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("GE"))
   error = false;
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("AU"))
   error = false;     
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("MX"))
   error = false;

  return error;
 }//end of error()

 public String getCountry(String locHA)
 {

  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("FR"))
   locHA = "France";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("GB"))
   locHA = "Great Britain";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("CA"))
   locHA = "Canada";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("JA"))
   locHA = "Japan";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("RU"))
   locHA = "Russia";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("GE"))
   locHA = "Germany";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("AU"))
   locHA = "Australia";
  if(locHA.equalsIgnoreCase("MX"))
   locHA = "Mexico";
  return locHA;    
 }//end of getCountry

 public String encrypt(String input)
 {
  int q; //this is going to be the length of the string array
  String encrypted = "meh"; //a holder for the encrypted message
  int limit; //the limit of the array  

  char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

  limit = charArray.length;

  for(int x = 0;x <= limit; x++)
  {
   if(charArray[x] == ('A'))
    charArray[x] = 'N';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('B'))
    charArray[x] = 'O';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('C'))
    charArray[x] = 'P';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('D'))
    charArray[x] = 'Q';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('E'))
    charArray[x] = 'R';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('F'))
     charArray[x] = 'S';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('G'))
    charArray[x] = 'T';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('H'))
    charArray[x] = 'U';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('I'))
    charArray[x] = 'V';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('J'))
    charArray[x] = 'W';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('K'))
    charArray[x] = 'X';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('L'))
    charArray[x] = 'Y';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('M'))
    charArray[x] = 'Z';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('N'))
    charArray[x] = 'A';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('O'))
    charArray[x] = 'B';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('P'))
    charArray[x] = 'C';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('Q'))
    charArray[x] = 'D';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('R'))
    charArray[x] = 'E';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('S'))
    charArray[x] = 'F';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('T'))
    charArray[x] = 'G'; 
   else if(charArray[x] == ('U'))
    charArray[x] = 'H';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('V'))
    charArray[x] = 'I';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('W'))
    charArray[x] = 'J';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('X'))
    charArray[x] = 'K';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('Y'))
    charArray[x] = 'L';
   else if(charArray[x] == ('Z'))
    charArray[x] = 'M'; 
   else 
   {
    x++;
    continue; 
   }                     
  }


  encrypted = charArray.toString();  
  return encrypted;
 }//end of encrypt

}//end of action class
```

The error is with my for loop at

```
for(int x = 0;x <= limit; x++)
```

The error I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Actions.encrypt(Actions.java:75)
    at Driver.message(Driver.java:74)
    at Driver.<init>(Driver.java:39)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:85)
```

I do not understand why it is trying to access the array outside the bounds. Thank you for your input and help. I am trying to figure this out for some time. It looks like it should work.

Comment: I don't see the for-loop in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code appears to have the Driver class twice.

Comment: The error is in Actions.encrypt, and you didn't post that code. Also, your code is unreadable. Indent it properly. IDEs do that with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I think you didn't pasted your Action class, can you add snippet for the encrypt method from Action class

Comment: Please condense to an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Sorry I seem to have messed up when copying my source code. It should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out @Gendarme

Comment: `charArray[limit]` will give you an `ArrayIndexBoundsOutOfException` because the last index is `limit-1`. You need to change the loop to `x < limit` instead of `x <= limit`. I do not know if this is the actual error you are experiencing right now, but if it isn't, it will be an error in the future.

Comment: I would suggest adding a debug print in the `encrypt()` method to ensure that the `input` parameter has a value. Also, the `for` loop is wrong as it will overrun at the end (as @Gendarme noted while I was typing :))

Comment: @Gendarme that did indeed get rid of my out of bounds error. However now it s not accepting input for message. It is just running through everything after I get the location. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Grimmjow91, did you examine (perhaps by a System.out.println()) the value of `input` before attempting the loop? If `input` is empty, the reason you no longer see the ArrayOutOfBounds issue is because the .length is 0, and the original incorrect for loop would have attempted to look at [0], which wasn't present.

Comment: @Kevin right now it is ignoring moo = keyboard.nextLine(); so I am not getting a string to pass to input. keyboard.next() works but that only gives me a one word string.

Comment: @Grimmjow91, may I suggest you post a new question focusing on the specific problem of obtaining the input, following the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve suggestions. To keep SO working, a question needs to be focused, and the problem of the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException has been resolved.

Comment: @KevinO Why does it say `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`, though? `0` is out of bounds? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: @KevinO I was going to work through it more on my own before I asked for more help. My exception error has been solved. It is a shame that I can't mark comments as answers. Thank you guys!

Comment: @Gendarme, the `char[]` array is empty, and thus has a length of 0. When the `for` loop was set to `x <= limit`, it would attempt to access the [0] element of the array. However, the array was empty -- a length of 0. There is therefore no [0] element to access. Try this: `String s = ""; char[] chr = s.toCharArray(); System.out.println(chr.length);     System.out.println(chr[0]);` and you will see a length of 0, and get the Exception with the index out of bounds at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap, the solution to the original problem was that the for loop should run to (x < limit) not (x <= limit).

And to answer your other question, the error "char cannot be dereferenced" occurs because ".equals" and ".compareTo" are for strings and at that time you are working with a char.

Comment: For future reference what would you suggest I use when comparing a char? Or is == ok when using a char?

Comment: Well, `.equals()` is defined on `Object`, so it is not limited to `String` objects. Primitives, such as `int` or `char` do not have methods.

Comment: What you could do actually is create an array containing the alphabet (and initialize it using ASCII characters) and compare your current array to the alphabet. In that fashion you could use an "=" instead and it would clean up your code a lot. Just a suggestion for the future. For now, "==" should be okay!